# Why my google places autocomplete is not working in angular10?

Tags: angular, google-maps

In my `angular` i have `Google Places` autocomplete implemented like this

component.html

```
<input #search id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" class="form-control">

<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.setCurrentLocation();
   this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          //get the place result
        const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

         //verify result
        if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
           return;
        }

         //set latitude, longitude and zoom
        this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    });
   });
 }
```

But problem is that map shows with current location correctly on map like this

[image]

but when i type any address in `input` so it's not showing any places `suggestions` upon typing. And no errors are showing in console. Everything is looks clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the actual problem. The problem was that suggestions list was showing behind the modal. So the issue with `z-index`. Modal `z-index` was greater than autocomplete suggestions list's `z-index` so i just put this in my main `style.css`

```
.pac-container{
  z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

This worked for me.